# Same component twice in page ngIf not working as expected

Tags: angular, google-maps

```
<div id="{{gMapConfig.id}}" class="g-map"></div>
<loader *ngIf="!googleReady||plottingData"></loader>
```

I have a map component with an overlay that I have to show when the map is loading or when data is being fetched.I have the same map component on page and in a modal,the ngif works on page but not in modal.

```
window['onMapsLoaded'] = (ev) => {
  this.googleReady = true;
}
plotMarkers() {
this.plottingData = true;
....
//after plotting markers
 this.plottingData = false;
}
```